# 1950s bathroom sink faucet leaking at handle

Tags: plumbing, faucet

This faucet is leaking at the handle (*just behind part that turns*) when water is turned on.

Does anyone know if this kind of fixture can be replaced, do they make something that fits a  1950s bathroom sink?

If I take out that screw and pull off the handle will I see the problem?  Is it a washer?

Can it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Yes it can repaired, Usually.  I do not have time to write up  full answer and i am sure there are already answers on here that address this issue. The washer can be replaced, the seat *may* need to be re-honed if it has been leaking for a long time.   Here is a video to give you better understanding of how your faucet can be repaired.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ia54Q6Twvt4

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/143753/repairing-a-leaky-valve-stem

Comment: New to site and don't know how to say thank you to Alaska Man so am doing it here in the comments.  Thank you!

Comment: a drip from the handle is usually the stem seal, it may be a packing bolt that can be tightened, or possibly O rings that must be replaced.